# MySQL: change TIME data type so always 24 hour format

Tags: mysql, sql, apache, ubuntu

In a project I'm working on I use the `TIME` data type a lot as well as all relevant functions. Currently I have to wrap every single time selection in time_format to get the times in 24 hour format. It would save me a lot of time if this was done by default.

Any ideas as to how I can change the default settings so the time data type is always formatted as 24 hour?

Comment: What's pulling the data? Do you need to deal with it as a string at all?

Comment: @JonSkeet The SQL query performs calculations with 24 hour time values. I just realised nothing was working and it's because I didn't realise MySQL times were 12 hour and not 24 hour. Take a peek: http://pastebin.com/rHYaUUUB

Comment: Take a peek at what, exactly? That's a massive blob of SQL - no indication what's wrong at all. You need to describe the issue with as small a piece of code as possible - and please edit it into your question, rather than linking elsewhere. It's still not at all clear that the problem isn't just in terms of a text representation...

Comment: @JonSkeet What isn't clear? All I'm saying is I want to display all TIME data types as 24 hour rather than 12 hour... that is quite a simple concept. It just means I won't have to include DATE_FORMAT around every 12 hour time

Comment: @VladimirOselsky I need the same thing for `time` format

Comment: My suggestion is that you fetch it as a value of a suitable data type rather than as a string - at which point your problem wouldn't be in SQL at all. Whether that's feasible in PHP or not, I don't know - your question doesn't actually mention PHP at the moment. Try to put text conversions as close to the UI as possible. What's unclear is what that huge chunk of SQL is actually meant to have to do with the question. Most of it has nothing to do with TIME.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky: I really hope it doesn't *store* the value as text at all, to be honest.